# Issue building with CMake in TeamCity

Tags: cmake, teamcity

I have installed the [Cmake Plugin](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/CMake+Plugin) to be able to build my C/C++ project with TeamCity. However, so far I had no luck building the project successfully. The build server and the agent are running on separate docker containers. The build fails with the following error:

```
[14:09:29] Step 1/1: DebugBuild (CMake build)
[14:09:29]   [Step 1/1] Starting: /bin/bash -c "cmake "$@" 2>&1" -- --build . --target suite_1_app --config Debug --
[14:09:29]   [Step 1/1] in directory: /opt/buildagent/work/3249fc82f6dadd5
[14:09:29]   [Step 1/1] --: cmake: command not found
[14:09:29]   [Step 1/1] Process exited with code 127
[14:09:30]   [Step 1/1] Process exited with code 127 (Step: DebugBuild (CMake build))
[14:09:30]   [Step 1/1] Step DebugBuild (CMake build) failed
[14:09:30] Publishing internal artifacts
[14:09:30] Build finished
```

And here is the configuration I used in the build step:

- Runner type: Cmake build
- Step name: DebugBuild
- Build target: suite_1_app
- Configuration: Debug

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The error message "cmake: command not found" tells, that `cmake` executable is not found. Have you installed CMake itself (not a plugin)?

Comment: You need to include cmake to your agent's docker image.

Comment: I have tried to install CMake on the TeamCity agent docker with no success. first I tried installing it with apt-get install and got the error E: Unable to locate package CMake. Then I tried installing CMake from source code and got the error that it cannot find appropriate C compiler on this system! 

What could be the problem? 

What is the right approach of including CMake?

Is there any special configuration for TeamCity CMake plugin?